# Linux ubuntu password recover

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking

Hi I had install my linux ubuntu in my window 7 platform but since I'm long time did not login and while I try to login again second time with my password..but It seems like doesn't work..can I remove this linux and reinstall a new version of linux ubuntu..will this action affect my window 7 later..could anyone bring me some idea? Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you currently dual boot Ubuntu and Windows and are now unable to log into windows?

Comment: yup~I'm using dual boot in my os.

Answer (score 0):

You surely can reinstall ubuntu. If you choose the right options in the partition layout step in the installer this will not affect your windows 7 installation.

But you can also google or search here for "ubuntu password recovery" and you will find a lot of solutions which can help you getting back your login to the ubuntu installation.

Comment: thank you for all your suggestion bro. I'd solve my problem and my Linux really working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using an encrypted home partition, the usual way to recover a ubuntu password is not to recover it at all - but rather to change it as root. Since ubuntu dosen't have a root password, you're going to need to boot into single user mode to change it.

If your system boots directly to ubuntu without showing grub, hold shift when booting to throw you into recovery mode - then there, select root. Then type in `passwd username` where username is your username, key in your password twice. You can then reboot the system and use your new password.

The process may be *significantly* more complicated with a encrypted home directory - maybe impossible

Comment: wow~! I will prefer using single mode with a virtual box is it more easier to run and recover?

Comment: By enter the command 'sudo su' in the terminal and try to recover the password in guest mode also working?

Comment: single user mode is insecure. *Do not do this*. This is only for changing your password, and fixing systems. You do not need sudo since you are root. su will do. I do not recommend doing anything other than changing your password in single user mode using the specific commands I have given. Then use a regular ubuntu session. single user mode is meant for advanced stuff that you don't normally do.

Comment: i see, okay I try use that..ya the command is 'su'..hehe

Answer (score -1):

Here are several options for password recovery:http://lmgtfy.com/?q=linux+password+recovery

If you find those options don't work for you or might be too much bother, you can do a reinstall of Ubuntu.

You won't have to remove your old Ubuntu, just install the latest version onto the same partition. Your Ubuntu files/settings will not be preserved. This requires that you have a basic knowledge of partitioning, however, so I wouldn't run the install blindly.

**This shouldn't affect Windows 7 if you do the partitioning right and make sure you don't screw up the GRUB installation. Just be aware that in order to boot Windows in the future you will have to select it from a list.**

Comment: thank u for your suggestion bro..I'll try for that partition before..and it work perfectly for me.

Comment: -1: [LMGTFY links are **not** acceptable.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links)